# Powershell ForEach-Object loop with a twist

Tags: html, powershell

We have this PowerShell script that we use to take out users from the AD. We recently moved to Windows Server 2012R2 from 2008R2 and noticed that the script no longer works. After a few tweaks and turns I have managed to get almost everything to work except this loop:

```
$mail += $nameofgroup | ForEach-Object {$mail += $_.Name+"<br>"}
```

This is to be sent via email later therefore we have the `$mail` variable.

Here is a code example:

Get info from AD:

```
$alla = Get-ADUser -filter 'name -like "*"' `
          -Properties extensionattribute2, extensionattribute14, extensionattribute15 | `
          Select-Object Name, Extensionattribute2, `
                        Extensionattribute14, Extensionattribute15
```

Sort the data:

```
$nameofgroup = $alla | where { `
     $.Extensionattribute14 -like "nameofgroup" -and `
     $.Extensionattribute15 -like "FULL"} | `
     Select-Object Name | Sort-Object Name
```

Post total amount of users:

```
$mail += "nameofgroup: " + ($nameofgroup).count + "<br>"
```

and then my line from before, I want this to list the users by "name"

```
$mail += $nameofgroup | ForEach-Object {$mail += $_.Name+"<br>"}
```

Can anyone spot a fault in this last line?

**Update:**

I just tried to `Write-Host $nameofgroup` to see if contains data and it does, so the problem is more or less why it won't print it to `$mail`.

Comment: _I have managed to get almost everything to work except this loop_ What does that mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: No, no errors, it simply just does not output any data for me when i later print it to the mail

Comment: Define "unable to work". Please provide examples of both what you expect the loop to produce, and what it actually produces.

Comment: @NiklasSjögren you can edit the question to add the additional information instead of putting it in an answer or comments.

Comment: *that we use to take out users* - what have they done to deserve this! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You append to `$mail` both inside and outside the loop. Decide on one or the other:

```psh
$mail += $nameofgroup | ForEach-Object { $_.Name+"<br>" }
```

or

```psh
$nameofgroup | ForEach-Object { $mail += $_.Name+"<br>" }
```

Comment: worked if i did this $nameofgroup | ForEach-Object {$mail += $_.Name+"<br>"}